# Editor placeholder in source file

Tags: swift

Following this ARKit tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8U8rGdMop4

But getting a

> Editor placeholder in source file

error in the following code (2nd line). Has there been a change in Swift that would cause this?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    addObject()
}
```

Comment: Where is `func addObject() {` in the rest of the file?

Answer (score 7):

There is a placeholder in your file, meaning that you'll see a grey or blue block, that'll say some value, indicating that you need to replace the placeholder with something of that value.

[The gray blocks in this image are placeholders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZo4c.png)

It is also possible that Xcode is just being idiotic, so try cleaning the project, then run it again.